# Does `std::find()` short circuit?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, c++03

Consider I had an `std::vector` such that its contents were `std::string`s and `{"a","b","c"}`. If I were to perform `std::find()` looking for `"a"`, would it stop once it iterated over `"a"` (ie. short-circuit) or continue to the end?

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.insert(vec.begin(), "a");
vec.insert(vec.begin(), "b");
vec.insert(vec.begin(), "c");
```

Which is faster?

```cpp
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "a");
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "c");
```

Comment: yes it does, why wouldn't it? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: Even if theoretically an implementation did continue until the end, who would use it? It would get naturally culled.

Comment: There is no requirement to stop at the first occurrence from the complexity requirements. But the typical implementation does so as shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the possible implimenation of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
constexpr InputIt find(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {  // if the condition met
            return first;       // ---> here returns the iterator
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

It will stop iterating, once it finds the match.

Comment: It might be worth to mention that `first` doesn't necessarily mean `begin()` of container. Hence, it can be used to search further after first hit.

Answer (score 5):

Based on description [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), yes it does.

> Returns the first element in the range [first, last) that satisfies
>   specific criteria.
>
> Complexity: At most last - first applications of the predicate

And by taking a look at its possible implementations it is stated that `std::find` uses short circuit

Answer (score 5):

The C++17 standard draft defines the behavior of `std::find` in [[alg.find]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.find) (only part relevant to overload used in question cited):

> `template<class InputIterator, class T>
>     InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>                        const T& value);`
>
> [...]
>
> *Returns*: The first iterator `i` in the range `[first, last)` for which the following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == value`, [...]. Returns `last` if no such iterator is found.
>
> *Complexity*: At most `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate.

Previous standard versions, including C++03, contain basically the same wording.

Nothing in this guarantees that the elements are searched in any specific order at all or that `std::find` must stop testing the predicate once it found a match.

However, since the function must return the *first* iterator in the range satisfying the condition, it makes no sense to test out-of-order, because if a match was found, all previous iterators would need to be tested for an earlier match anyway.

Once a match is found it is also pointless to continue applying the predicate and the standard only requires the predicate to be applied "*at most*" as often as there are elements in the range.

Therefore any reasonable sequential implementation of `std::find` will search the iterator range in-order and return when a match is found. If an implementation did not do that, users would complain about it as soon as they noticed. Standard library implementors want their code to be fast where possible and they have no benefit letting their code do more work than necessary.

I suppose though that an implementation could make use of parallelization if it knows that this will not cause data races for the given types and in that case it might happen that the search examines iterators beyond the first match. Whether something like this is implemented in any standard library for the non-parallel `std::find` overload from the question, I don't know.